# Access NSArray from dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a chat application. When I send push notification from the `server`, it sends me a `NSArray` value which I use it to forward user profile with `NSNumber`.

I printed push notification response with alertview and I added response picture. You can see the response of push notification.

I talked about `"customDictionary"` key. I want to access this `'6297'` value and after I want to convert to `NSNumber`.

Here is my code:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *userID;

NSArray *array = [[[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"customDictionary"]array];
NSString *myArrayString = [array description];
NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
format.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
self.userID = [format numberFromString:myArrayString];
```

userID is returning null. Is anybody can help me ? Thank you.

[image: push notification sends me these values]

Comment: replace this one `NSArray *array = [[[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"customDictionary"]array];` to this `NSArray *array = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"customDictionary"]array];`.

Comment: I dont think your value for key "customDictionary" is array it a string value

Comment: @HuyNghia i think you are right.

Comment: Also, you should never use the `.description` property - this is just for logging

Comment: @HuyNghia Thank you for your answering. If you think "customDictionary" is string value, how can I get off(trim) "[ ]" these characters ? Is Saif answers correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your key "aps" give you a dictionary which actually doesn't contain the "customDictionary" key, its outside of your "aps" dictionary. Try the code given below. Good luck!!

```
NSArray *array = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"customDictionary"] array];
NSString *myArrayString = [array description];
NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
format.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
self.userID = [format numberFromString:myArrayString];
```

Comment: ooooo, how can I do this mistake. "Aps" key doesn't contain "customDictionary". Yes it is outside. I used Saif trim method and I accessed the value. Thank you so much!.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the value of key 'customDictionary' is string, try this

```
NSString *unformattedString = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"customDictionary"];
NSCharacterSet *specialCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"[]"];
NSString *newString = [unformattedString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:specialCharSet];
NSLog(@"newString : %@",newString);
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for answering Saif. newString returned null. I don't need alert value but I tried to access it and I accessed the alert value with NSString *alert = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"]valueForKey:@"alert"];. Alert value is string but I don't think 'customDictionary' value is string. Trimming event is a good idea but It didn't work, why is it not work ? What do you think?

Comment: "Aps" key doesn't contain "customDictionary". I didn't realise that. Now, your answer is working, thank you.